# Ubuntu 22.04 after installing python3.11 upgrade fails

Tags: apt, python3

After I installed python3.11 and 3.11-venv (already have 3.10), whenver I try to apt upgrade, I get this message (translated)

```
python3-dev: Depends: python3 (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) aber 3.10.6-1~22.04 is already installed
             Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) aber 3.10.6-1~22.04 is already installed
             Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 4.3) aber 4.3.2-1 is already installed
```

I am no longer able to do anything, I even tried to remove 3.11 again, but all I get is a message to use `apt --fix-broken install`

If I do that, I get (translated)

```
Unpacking of python3-distutils (3.10.6-1~22.04) over (3.10.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: Error while editing the archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 Tried overwriting »/usr/lib/python3.11/distutils/README«, which is also in package python3.11-distutils 3.11.0~rc2-1+jammy1
Preparing unpacking of .../python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking of python3-lib2to3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) over (3.10.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: Error while editing the archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 Tried overwriting »/usr/lib/python3.11/lib2to3/Grammar.txt«, which is also in package python3.11-lib2to3 3.11.0~rc2-1+jammy1
Error while editing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.10.6-1~22.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At this point in time, I just want everything to work again, even if I have to remove python3.11. Is there any way with for example dpkg to achieve that? Please Help

Comment: Did you replace the system python with python3.11?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem, So I did

```
sudo dpkg -r python3.11-distutils python3.11-lib2to3 python3.11-venv
```

after that

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

and it worked

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I was looking at the bug, that was no longer considered a bug, and was hoping to find something to run to fix the issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3-stdlib-extensions/+bug/1990593 I am curious, what version of python are your running as your default 3.10, or 3.11?